# User experience evaluation: How to use AttrakDiff?

Tags: users, experience

How can AttrakDiff measure pragmatic quality of a website if users just visit the site, maybe for the first time. Lets say it is a shop, and they haven't bought anything yet. Does this matter?

Pragmatic Quality (PQ):
Describes the usability of a product and indicates how successfully users are in achieving their goals using the product.

Answer (score 1):

Hassenzhal's Attrakdiff is a powerful tool to measure both hedonic quality and pragmatic quality (task oriented). I suggest provide the users with some tasks to execute on the website to simulate the purchase or depending what you wanna measure. Following the task, ask the participants to fill the semantic differential questionnaire. Let me know how do you analyze the data.

Comment: Thanks. What if i want to make a comparison test between exsisting website and a re-design - but the re-design is only a muck-up, there is no interacting on the re-design. Is attrakDiff then suitable for this ?

Comment: "Let me know how do you analyze the data." - i am not sure. Attrakdiff makes a pdf with results. What more could i do ?

Comment: I would take screen shots of the existing website and compare it with the mock-ups of the re-designed one. In this way you are avoiding any confounding factor - interactive v/s static webpages. You can do your own statistical analysis using a t-test.

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking about this. But Attrakdiff measure also usability which is not needed when i only have a muck-up right ? What do you think ?

Comment: It depends what you intend to measure using the AttrakDiff -- PQ, HQ-S, HQ-I or AT? Use each component accordingly. Let me know if that answers your problem, and share how did you analyze the data from each of the component.